# How to load FeatureDefinitionScope value via csom?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, csom, feature, feature-receiver

I load features using the code bellow:

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web site = clientContext.Web;
FeatureCollection collFeature = site.Features;

clientContext.Load(collFeature);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I also need a scope of each feature. I mean value of [FeatureDefinitionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.featuredefinitionscope.aspx) type. Do you know how load this value via `csom` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, you will only retrieve all features with scope "Web". There is actually a difference between features scoped to a site ("Web" class) or to a site collection ("Site" class).

The following adjusted code retrieves all active features for the site collection and the site:

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Site siteCollection = clientContext.Site;
Web site = clientContext.Web;

FeatureCollection siteCollectionFeatures = siteCollection.Features;
FeatureCollection siteFeatures = site.Features;

clientContext.Load(siteCollectionFeatures);
clientContext.Load(siteFeatures);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I'm certain that you won't be able to access WebApplication and Farm features with CSOM (SharePoint client-side object model). As you want to support SharePoint Online, that's your barrier.

If you only want to go for SharePoint OnPremise (SharePoint Foundation or Server), you could go for SSOM (SharePoint server-side object model), which Jerry_MSFT described above. WebApplication features could then be accessed using `web.Site.WebApplication.Features` (*web* is your [SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb?view=sharepoint-server) class). But you don't have that possibility in CSOM.

Comment: Yes. thanks. But what about the other features - `Farm` ?

Comment: See my addition to the post above. I'm sure that you won't be able to achieve that using CSOM.

Comment: and moreover there're WebApp Features also

Answer (score 2):

In CSOM Feature Object, there is no "FeatureDefinitionScope", please check the documentation:

[image]

[Feature properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.feature_properties.aspx)

If you are using SharePoint On-Premise Environment, you can use the Server Object Model below to get this property:

```
   SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/dev/");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    foreach (SPFeature feature in site.Features)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(feature.FeatureDefinitionScope);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. But of course I've already checked the official documentation for many times and have not found it. And unfortunately I can't use server object model. So this answer is an answer for kinda different question. I need csom. But anyway thanks.

Comment: @isxaker, what's your SharePoint version, Online or On-Premise ?

Comment: I need a solution for both type of SP.